# How to Export Shapefile Attribute to Text Layer in CAD Using FME

Tags: fme-form, annotation, cad

How can I export a Shapefile's Attribute to Text Layer in CAD Using FME.

For example I have a Shapefile of Parcels and it contains a ParcelID field. Now I would like to display that field attributes as CAD Text Annotation layer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Labeller or LabelPointReplacer transformer. Both of those will create annotation. Then use the DWGStyler (assuming your CAD output is DWG) to assign a style, size, rotation, font, etc to the annotation.